# Why am I getting invalid syntax error while installing packages with pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, boto3

In Debian server when I am installing boto3 using pip I get the following error:

```
$ python3.2 -m pip install boto3

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/runpy.py", line 161, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/runpy.py", line 74, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import USER_CACHE_DIR, src_prefix

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils import appdirs

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/appdirs.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.compat import WINDOWS, expanduser

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/compat.py", line 62

return u"".join(u"\\x%x" % c for c in raw_bytes), err.end

             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Note: pip version is 18.1**

Comment: Try using  just `pip install boto3`.

Comment: pip install boto3 gave "/usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory" error whereas 
pip3 install boto3 gave the same error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Do you have `pip` installed? Check it through `which pip`.

Comment: yes. Which pip shows: /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: Use this path in actual pip command.

Comment: Tried command with actual path but still no luck. Getting the same issue as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Try installing pip3 and then install boto3 using pip3.

Comment: pip3 is already installed. which pip3 shows: /usr/local/bin/pip3

Comment: Use this to install, `/usr/local/bin/pip3 install boto3`.

Comment: I have already done that as mentioned in my first reply. It gives the same error as mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The syntax - **u"".join** is not supported in python3.2.

pip3(which was same as pip3.2) while running the scripts for installing boto3 faced the syntax and threw the exception.

I installed python 3.6 and on running "pip3.6 install boto3", it worked.

Note: My python project is new and small one, so changing from python3.2 to python3.6 did not affect much, but with large or existing project this may not be feasible. Just want anyone who may face the situation to know the reason for this issue.